# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: Functional Testing: Numbers not being passed as string in params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Note * I'm using Factory_girl, not sure if that matters here

Currently, I do the following to prep for doing a post:

```
  p = Factory.build(:le_object, :template_id => t.id.to_s)
```

Notice that I am deliberately converting it to a string

And then I just do your ordinary post:

```
  post :create, :le_object => p.attributes
```

But, what is fishy, is when I look in the test log, I see this:

```
Parameters: {"action"=>"create", ... "template_id"=>0, ... }
```

Notice how the id is NOT a string.

Now, this messes up the controller, because I do a `not .empty?` check on that field (because it is optional), and then that method in the controller does something entirely different.

This works fine in the app, when it is actually running, as for the same method, the console outputs this in dev / production:

```
Parameters: {"action"=>"create", ... "template_id"=>"1"...}
```

Notice how here the 1 is a string, because it came from a form, and in HTTP, everything is strings.

This is what in my code is failing, specifically:

```
if not params[:le_object][:template_id].nil? and not params[:le_object][:template_id].empty?
```

The issue currently, is that in the test, because it's passing a number, instead of the string representation, I'm getting the error `undefined method empty? for #:Fixnum`

So... How do I change my code (test or otherwise) such that I can get this to work?

Comment: Why not just use `.blank?` instead, which will return true if the item is `nil` or if it's a blank string.

Comment: strings don't have .blank?. it would be same issue though. Numbers don't have a .blank? method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails defines the `.blank?` method on `Object`, meaning it works on just about anything (strings, numbers, etc.) The definition of `.blank?` is very simple:

```
respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
```

It will default to use `empty?`, but if that method doesn't exist on the object, it will just call `!self`. If the item is `nil`, then `!nil` will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: how does that work? because !"" and !"text" both return false. I need then to return two different things. That's why I'm using blank. Because in HTML, everything is a string, "" has to be considered the same as nil.

Comment: also, for example, 4.empty? returns undefined method.  Same with blank.

Comment: In Rails, `4.blank?` returns `false`, not an undefined method. Your controller really shouldn't care if it comes in as a string or a number, just call `params[:template_id].blank?` and it'll return `true` if the parameter doesn't exist or if it's a blank string, and it'll return false when it's `0` or `"0"`.

Comment: Sorry bro. You must be talking about a version of rails that isn't 2.3.8

Because, I'm not delusional. 4.blank? is undefined method for FixedNum. same with Empty.  I was thinking though that maybe it is something weird going on with the testing framework.... idk. =\

Comment: `.blank?` has existed since Rails 2.0.0. That's super strange that `4.blank?` is not working -- and you're definitely doing that in Rails, not just in an IRB prompt?

Comment: I'm doing it in both. Both don't work. I tried irb in the console. and my app uses rails 2.3.8. =\   Is there a rails console?

Comment: Run `script/console` for Rails 2.3.8